# Removing the Total Row on a table with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove the total row on a table with VBA as when loading data it won't allow the data to be entered within the table it goes below the total row.

Once the data has been loaded I want the Total Row to be active again so it can total up the rows.

I have code for a Pivot table but cannot figure out how to do it with a standard table.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I have search the web high and low!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by total row?  Please clarify or post the spreadsheet

Comment: In a table's design you can tick the box to show Total Row. This feature when turned on stops you from entering more data into the table. With VBA I want to turn this feature off and then back on again once the relevant data has been added.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? Not sure what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: I have this for a pivot table:
Sub NoSubtotals()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

On Error Resume Next
For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
    
pf.Subtotals(1) = True
pf.Subtotals(1) = False
 Next pf
Next pt

End Sub

As I said though, I am wondering if it is possible to turn off the Total row feature on a table, not a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was trying to achieve.

```
Sub RemoveTotalRow()
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Processing")

tbl.TotalsRowRange.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

This is assuming you have the table in Sheet1 and that you only have one table. Update as needed.

```
Sheet1.ListObjects.Item(1).ShowTotals = False
```